# tablesorter group subtotal based trigger col 0 add col 1

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I am trying to total the AMOUNT column with the vendor column changes. In other words the total of Harry Amount and the total of Mark amount.  I would also like to put the total in the amount column under each group.

EDIT - I would really like this to "click" on the column automatically, in other words the subtotal will already be there. sorted by the 1st column but totals in the 2nd column.

What I would like it to look like is this:  Sort by column 0 and sub total in column 1

```
Mark    100.22
        232.12
 Total  342.34

Harry    23.21
         11.11
  Total  34.32
```

EDIT - Added this [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/mworsnop/tf59zL8c/12/)

[image]

```
$("#invoicesraw").tablesorter({
    theme : "blue",

    widgets: [ "group", "columns", "columnSelector", "zebra" ],
    widgetOptions: {




        group_callback    : function($cell, $rows, column, table){
            if (column === 1) {
                var subtotal = 0;
                $rows.each(function(){
                    subtotal += parseFloat( $(this).find("td").eq(column).text() );
                });
                $cell.find(".group-count").append("; subtotal: " + subtotal );
            }
        },
        // event triggered on the table when the grouping widget has finished work
        group_complete    : "groupingComplete",


        columnSelector_container : $('#selector'),
        columnSelector_columns : {
            0: 'disable',
            1: 'disable',
            2: 'disable'
        },
        columnSelector_mediaquery: false
    }
});
```

This is a sample of the OUTPUT when using the totals, NOTE the group name line is not formatted.

```
    Vendor,Amount
"<i></i><span class=“;group-name“;>harry smith</span><span class=“;group-count“;> (5)</span>","<i></i><span class=“;group-name“;>harry smith</span><span class=“;group-count“;> (5)</span>"
Harry Smith,3222.00
Harry Smith,2345.21
Harry Smith,121.00
Harry Smith,1.00
Harry Smith,21.00
Total:,5710.21
"<i></i><span class=“;group-name“;>mark worsnop</span><span class=“;group-count“;> (1)</span>","<i></i><span class=“;group-name“;>mark worsnop</span><span class=“;group-count“;> (1)</span>"
Mark Worsnop,3434.00
Total:,3434.00
```

I added the outputTable to the demo but its not triggering. Not sure why as thats the same code I have in my test website. I am not very well versed in JSFiddle.

Here is the latest demo [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/mworsnop/tf59zL8c/18/)

Note sure why but on JSFiddle it looks great. On my test website it adds the names to the CSV like this

```
    Vendor,Amount
harry smith (5),harry smith (5)
Harry Smith,3222.00
Harry Smith,2345.21
Harry Smith,121.00
Harry Smith,1.00
Harry Smith,21.00
Total:,5710.21
mark worsnop (1),mark worsnop (1)
Mark Worsnop,3434.00
Total:,3434.00
```

Comment: It would be easier to help if you set up a demo ([modify this one](https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/4ac5kr3o/)). I think all you'll need to do is use `$row` to find the name in the vendor column, then use it to add up the subtotal for that person.

Comment: Added a demo Mottie sure appreciate the help!

Comment: I'm uncertain as to how to display the total for each person when sorting the "Amount" column. Would you please jump on [IRC or Gitter](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter#questions) to clarify what you want.

Comment: I added a small example above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `group_callback` function as follows ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/tf59zL8c/1/)):

```
group_callback    : function($cell, $rows, column, table){
    if (column === 0) {
        var subtotal = 0;
        $rows.each(function(){
            subtotal += parseFloat( $(this).find("td").eq(1).text() );
        });
        $cell.find(".group-count").append("; total: " + subtotal.toFixed(2) );
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great! Thanks you! Is there a way to have the column "clicked" when its displayed and also have the total under the column with the amounts?  Like the example I added

Comment: The other thing I noticed is that if I add the full name of the person, TS only displays the first name.?

Comment: You can set the [`sortList` option](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#sortlist) to apply an initial sort. To get the full name use a `"group-text"` class name ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/tf59zL8c/14/)). As for having the total *after* the group, the grouping widget isn't set up that way; but you might be able to add another row using the `group_callback`.

Comment: Here is a *very ugly hack* that inserts rows *after* each group. I wouldn't recommend using it in production, but as you can see it is possible. I'll take a look at the grouping widget when I get some time, so you won't need to use the code in [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/tf59zL8c/15/).

Comment: When I OUTPUT this table to a CSV the Name Total row doesnt come out correctly. I will add the example above.

Comment: Are you using the output widget for that? Please provide a demo.

Comment: I added the output to the demo at the bottom of the info above. Please see notes there.

Comment: [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/tf59zL8c/19/). 1) Remove "remove-me" class in `group_callback` 2) Set `output_includeHTML` to `false` 3) Don't float the `TD`, instead float a span inside. 4) Set `output_trimSpaces` to `true` for a nice output.

Comment: Very cool. Mottie I REALLY APPRECIATE ALL THE HELP!  Thank you so much!

Comment: Look at the output sample above at the end. y actual website added the name and count(). The JSFiddle doesnt do that. I copied the JS so not sure what else is happening?  Any idea?

Comment: I'm not sure why the group header is included in your output. It shouldn't be because the output widget ignores them. Make sure *all* of the files (core and widgets) are the most up-to-date versions.

Comment: That fix it.  Where is the part that displays the group header? Is there a way to disable the count?

Comment: Please look at [the documentation](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-grouping.html#group_count)

Comment: It never ceases to amaze me all this does. Thank you. For future reference where would I download all the js files? I grabbed then from JSFiddle this time but assume there is somewhere better?

Comment: The most up-to-date files are always at https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter - there are numerous ways to get it - https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter#download